# Can someone describe a good/easy mental procedure to choose the best move here?

Tags: theory, strategy, puzzles, middlegame

This is kind of like magic to me. Once they show you it becomes obvious :) :(

Can someone point out a good/easy strategy that a player can mentally train/use to decide what is the best move here for black?

**Note:** Guys, there is a best move for black there can lead to a checkmate later. The goal is not to find it, but to come up with a procedure to find it so it can be applied to other positions.

[image]

Comment: There are many tempting moves, but I'm guessing `1... Rxe3`.

Comment: Could you please reupload the image with the red arrows removed? They are very distracting in my opinion.

Comment: @Sid: I have edited the post with proper diagram.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Good but the new diagram does not have the same position as before, now there is an additional black knight on f6.

Comment: @Sid I've removed the additional knight.

Comment: If there's a decisive move for Black I'm not seeing it. The only tactics that come to mind are to deflect the Queen so the Knight on `a4` drops, or fork various pieces by placing a Knight on `e4` or `b2`.

Comment: Guys, there is a best move for black. The goal is not to find it, but to come up with a procedure to find it so it can be applied to other positions.

Comment: Some relevant points: White has abandoned the kingside, has a loose knight on `a4` and a weird bishop on `b1`. On the other hand white has an extra pawn, and if they can consolidate and improve piece coordination they will be better. Which means that black has to strike NOW.

Comment: All your pieces are doing something except your queen. Qe3 seems good to me, piling on the pressure on the weak spot e3 and ideas of Bh3.

Comment: Huh what happened there? I meant Qg5 of course. The algorithm is: improve your worst-placed piece.

Comment: First, look for patterns, for instance, Q on c2 and R on d1 is a fork pattern.

Second, look for tactical possibilities, for instance, N on e3 would be a fork if R takes pawn on e3.

Third, look for captures, for instance, Rxa4 Qxa4 would lead to a fork with Nb3 if the N on d3 wasn't there.

Note: I'm sure that this is a DRAWISH position as it will lead to an opposite-colored Bishops endgame.

Comment: Kotov's "Think Like a Grandmaster" might be helpful. It gives techniques on this very topic.  http://www.amazon.com/Think-Like-Grandmaster-Alexander-Kotov/dp/0713478853

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it smells. The OP wants to know a technique to find the proper move, and then accepts hos own 0-upvoted answer that says, "there is no technique" when we know this is not true at all.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I guess there is none logical strategy to follow. You just need to try to calculate in your head somehow and use intuition.

Comment: I think adding an answer yourself, just to accept it, is not really in the spirit of stackexchange …

Comment: Given @BlindKungFuMaster's answer, clearly this answer is wrong...

Answer (score 6):

I would say there are two tactical possibilities for black here:

- 1…Bxd3 2.Rxd3 Rxa4 3.Qxa4 Nxb2 wins the pawn back with a better position (the a3 pawn is now weak).
- 1…Rxe3 2.fe Nxe3 3.Qe2/d2 Bxd4 and the a4 Knight is hanging and the d1 rook is hanging with check … it still isn't over, in a game you should probably calculate further, but I'm to lazy to do that now.

There actually is an easy rule to find both of these tactical strikes:

Consider all captures!

Usually this rule is even broader: Consider all forcing moves! This includes captures, checks and attacks on stronger pieces.

Disclaimer: As with all rules this maxim has to be tempered by experience.

Comment: I don't think the former suggestion is very good; after 4. Qb3 Nxd3 5. Bxd3 Black has a worse pawn structure than White if anything. This is because while each side has a weak pawn (b7 and a3), it would be more serious for Black to lose their b7 pawn since the c6 pawn would be very weak and backwards afterwards. The position is pretty equal though but I would prefer to play White.

That being said, the second suggestion looks pretty nice to me.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't see Qb3, but I guess you can play 5…Qa5 anyway, so you don't end up totally passive. Anyway, it regains the pawn and should be considered.

Comment: It is true that it returns the pawn and results in a endgame that's probably a draw. You clearly have a good tactical eye. However, in the original position Black already has more than adequate compensation for the pawn (even without the winning Rxe3 sacrifice) and therefore doesn't need to simplify like that. :-)